# Combine two arrays and how to use it in foreach?

Tags: php, arrays, json

i have two arrays

```
[id_price] => {"9":"1000.000","10":"2000.000"}
```

and the second one

```
[id_cur] => {"9":"USD","10":"USD"}
```

now i want to combine this two arrays using key values please check the below code you ill get some idea thank you.

```
     $id_price = $_POST['id_price'];
     $id_cur = $_POST['id_cur'];

     $phpArray = json_decode($id_price, true);
     $phpArray_2 = json_decode($id_cur, true);

     foreach ($phpArray as $key => $value)
        { 

             now here i need to get the
             values of Currency and Price based on Key value (ID)

            Example if ID(key) : 9 then $Currency = USD , $Price =1000.000
         }
```

now i am getting out inside foreach

in this foreach
$key =>9 , 10 etc..,
$value => 1000.000 , 2000.000 etc..,

but i need the $phparray_2 currency value also inside foreach now

Comment: Please add your current output and your expected output

Comment: `foreach ($phpArray as $key => $value) { $output[] = array('currency' => $phpArray_2[$key], 'price' => $value); }`

Comment: So you want to show 1000.000USD like this right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$value` will contain the price and by using `$key` you can also get the units from `$phpArray_2`. But it is considered that the keys will be same and the values will be consistent. Try with -

```
    foreach ($phpArray as $key => $value)
    { 
        echo $value. ' '. $phpArray_2[$key];
    }
```